# How to output XML node with same name[multiple occurrences] but different values using an XQuery

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xquery, xquery-sql, xquery-3.0

I have a requirement where an XML element node say 'UseCountIds' having multiple occurrences and with multiple values . As element node name remain same, I need to distinguish each of these as UseCountIds1,UseCountIds2,UseCountIds3.

As of now, it is equipped to have only 3 occurrences.

Response payload appears as below . On which Xquery to be executed.

```
           <entries>
                <id>1</id>
                <UseCountIds>100</UseCountIds>
                <UseCountIds>200</UseCountIds>
                <UseCountIds>300</UseCountIds>
          </entries>
```

Using an Xquery , it is expected to output to delimited file.

```
        Output File
         id,UseCountIds1,UseCountIds2,UseCountIds3
         1,100,200,300
```

Expecting your valuable thoughts.

Comment: Basically, looking to extract same named element nodes as unique ones. Also, if no data is available for all nodes or any, let it output as blank or default values.

Answer (score 1):

If the tag structure of your XML input is fixed and only the values are variable, then the simplest query would be

```
concat(
  "id,UseCountIds1,UseCountIds2,UseCountIds3&#xa;",
  string-join(/entries/*, ',')
)
```

A more generic solution that works with any child tags might be

```
declare function f:label($element as element()) as xs:string {
  if (count($element/../*[node-name(.)=node-name($element)]) gt 1)
  then concat(local-name($element), count($element/preceding-sibling::*[node-name(.)=node-name($element)]))
  else local-name($element)
};

concat(string-join(/entries/*/f:label(.), ','), '&#xa;',
string-join(/entries/*, ',')
```